# How to add depth to spring's transaction manager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, aop

Spring 2.5, Hibernate.

Our application is architected to have a services layer and a manager layer. The services layer provides all read only services and communicates to the UI the results. For services requiring changes to the database, the services layer performs all initial read-only functions, then calls the manager layer.

We have set up a transaction advice around our manager layer to catch all exceptions coming out of the manager layer and rollback those transactions. This works pretty well for the most part.

The problem is in situations where we have one manager call another manager to perform some functionality. This functionality throws an exception, which is a real exception when called from the UI, but is handled internally in the client manager and a successful result is returned. The transaction manager sees that an exception was thrown and rolls back the transaction anyway, even though the exception was handled successfully.

Here is the transaction attribute that's causing us grief.

```
<tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="Throwable" no-rollback-for="OverridableException"/>
```

Is there a way that I can specifiy depth on this? I would like to say, only rollback for exceptions in the highest manager layer call and not for the exceptions in subsequent calls on the same transaction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up refactoring the inside service method to pull out the piece that was throwing the exception into another method. I then call that method to pre-approve what I'm doing from my outside service and call the new method from the inside service to throw the exception. In this way, I've circumvented the exception being thrown.

Wish there was a better way without committing more often.:(

Answer (score 2):

Typically you want to wrap the calls to the service layer in transactional advice, so that if your one service class makes several calls to different managers, all of that is wrapped in a single transaction - if you are making changes, all of them succeed or rollback together. This is usually known as (among other names) a [Unit of Work pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html).

So my advice would be to reconsider where you apply your transaction definitions. But if this is not doable, you might want to change the transaction advice to `propagation=REQUIRES_NEW`, so that each manager call starts a new transaction - and thus rolling back an inner transaction when one manager class calls another does not rollback the entire transaction.

Comment: The problem is that that will not fix the problem. I would still want my manager to call another manager to hide it's relationship and to encapsulate the functionality. The second call will still generate a rollback.

Thanks for the REQUIRES_NEW. I will need to discuss this with our team and make sure this fits. I have my concerns about creating an independent transaction.

Comment: I might be confused on the root problem you need to solve though with the exceptions thrown by the nested manager call. Does that exception leave the outer manager? Is it caught in the outer manager, or the inner one?

Comment: Thrown by the inner manager, caught and handled by the outer manager.